# How to create a Azure Service Principal with more than one subscription at its scope using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Basically the title. I want to create a service Principal who has access to more than 1 subscription.

I can create a service principal with access to one subscription as follows:

```bash
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <service_principal_name> --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/<subscription_id>
```

But I need 2 subscriptions as scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **scopes** parameter is a space-separated list of scopes.

**--scopes**

> Space-separated list of scopes the service principal's role assignment applies to. e.g., subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup, /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111122223333/resourceGroups/myGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM.

as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create)

Comment: I had tried the space thing before (even tried commas when it didn't work) and was getting error. Just tried it again and it worked!